# Catch a connection failure?

Tags: android

I am using SAXParserFactory and XML reader for fetching from the API.But sometimes when the internet connection goes down,it is getting stuck and application is getting crashed.

I am not so good in the concept of exception handling and all. I want that operation to be stopped and want to show a custom message, when connection fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
try {
   ... do the IO and SAX parsing
} catch (Exception e) {
  Toast.makeToast(context, "Failure: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Having said that: in Android 3 and later, your network IO needs to be in a background task (the system will kill your app when you do network IO in the UI thread), so that you need to put the io in background, which by definition can not access the UI.

Here a pattern like (pseudocode) can help:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

  String doInBackground() {

     try { 
         ... do IO / parsing
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
         return e.getMessage();
     }
     return "ok";
  }

  onPostExecute(String in) {
    Toast.makeToas(... in ... );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code which details how to perform network communications in Android:

```
try {
url = new URL(ForumURL);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
//Set connection time out to 10 secs
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(10*1000);

int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();    
if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
 {
    InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
    dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document dom = db.parse(in);
 } //You can put an else condition here, if you want to process any error situations.

} catch (Exception e) { 
    //Your exception handler code here.
    return;
  }//catch (Exception e)
```

A word of caution. When performing network communications in Android, make are you do it using a separate thread, and NOT from the main UI thread. The reason for this is, android OS will kill your app with ANR if you perform a network operation on slow networks.

Comment: To catch all Exceptions via `catch(Exception e)` is a very bad practice. You should better catch `IOException` or other more specific exceptions. For example a `OutOfMemoryException` would break your programm on other parts maybe too.